# Trying to figure out the sum of a certain variable not total sum using sql

Tags: sql, sum

I'm having a mindblank here but my question is quick.

I have a table like the following:

```
Cust    Part    Qty    Rtn Qty 
Joe      A1      2        0 
Joe      A2      3        1 
Joe      A1      2        2
Bob      A1      3        4
Bob      A2      4        0
```

I want the results to be like:

```
Joe      A1      4        2
Joe      A2      3        1
Bob      A1      3        0
Bob      A2      4        0
```

I'm trying to figure out how to create a sum for each customer individually according to the part?

Comment: What are the last 2 columns you're looking for?  It's not clear.

Comment: Shouldn't (Bob, A1) have Rtn Qty = 4 in result?

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a straightforward `group by` on `Cust, Part`:

```
select  Cust
,       Part
,       sum(Qty)
,       sum([Rtn Qty])
from    YourTable
group by
        Cust
,       Part
```